# MYSQL/PHP: Comparing large sets of 2 specific rows in one table (POKER-calculator)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, calculator, poker

I am writing an online poker calculator just for fun :)
I tried the pure php calculation approach, to compare two hands it calculates the outcome for every possible deck (C(5,48) = 1712304 decks)
That takes around 12 seconds on my sucky one.com server :D What is ofcourse far too slow if i would ever put it online for public.
So I tried a new approach, databases, I stored all the combinations for 7 cards (hand + deck) in a database. So I have a database of 5gb over 130mil rows with a primary key (the deck representation in binary) and the `points or rank` of those 7 cards.

So lets say the columns are called `a` and `b`, where `a` is the primary key.

I now want/need to compare the `b` where (`a` = x) and (`a` = y)
but again in the worst case for : C(5,48).

So for example in badly written code :

```
$ar = array(array(1,4),array(53,422),array(4423423,472323),array(71313,13131));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ar);$i++)
{
    $value_one = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('select `b` from `hugetable` where (`a` = ' . $ar[$i][0] ' . LIMIT 1;'))['b'];
    $value_two = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('select `b` from `hugetable` where (`a` = ' . $ar[$i][1] ' . LIMIT 1;'))['b'];
    if ($value_one > $value_two)
        $win++;
    elseif ($value_one < $value_two)
        $lose++;
    else
        $draw++;
}
```

So the question is, is there a faster way ?
Also is there a direct way to do this and get a table win `win` `draw` `loss` back immediately?

All help and answers are welcome!!! :)

EDIT:
This approach clearly didnt work out very good haha :D
it took around 100 seconds :D

Any other ideas are welcome !

Comment: I would suggest porting your PHP to Java.  A naive port should get to less than 1 second.

Comment: aye wrote it in javascript now haha, takes like 200ms crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that is worth trying is to let the database do most of the work.  Transfer your array to a temporary table with the primary keys of the matches to compare:

```
create temporary table match_list (int pk1, int pk2);
```

Now you can query the bigger table for the win/loss/draw statistics:

```
select  sum(case when t1.score > t2.score then 1 end) as wins
,       sum(case when t1.score < t2.score then 1 end) as losses
,       sum(case when t1.score = t2.score then 1 end) as draws
from    match_list
join    match_results t1 force index (pk_match_results)
on      t1.pk = match_list.pk1
join    match_results t2 force index (pk_match_results)
on      t2.pk = match_list.pk2
```

I've added the [`force index` hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html) which might help for a relatively small number of lookups to a very large table.  You can find the name for an index using `show index from mytable`.

Comment: Thank you for helping :) I tried this code unfortunately it's too slow :(
I even left out the draws and used 500 inserts at once per query to speed things up. But alas still too slow, the page times out in the browser, it does write the good result in a text file on the server so it does work like a charm but too slow :)
Maybe its just impossibru to get so much stuff out of a db of 5gb haha :D